# I'm hit with: undefined constant register_sidebar. Once in debug mode?

Tags: sidebar, debug

I'm attempting to test my theme and I switched my config to debug true and I'm now hit with *"Notice: Use of undefined constant register_sidebar - assumed 'register_sidebar'"*
I'm struggling to fix and was thinking it might be the way I've registered my sidebars. I have one in the footer and one in the main sidebar section.

**Functions.php**

```
if (function_exists(register_sidebar)) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Footer Widgets',
    'id' => 'footer-widgets',
    'description' => 'Place widgets for the footer here',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="one-third column footer-widget droided-body">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>'
));

//MAIN SIDEBAR
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Main Sidebar',
    'id' => 'main-sidebar',
    'description' => 'Place widgets for your sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="twelve columns droided-box droided-sidebar">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>'
)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the use of function_exists is like that

```
function_exists("register_sidebar")
```

Comment: the conditional check is totally unnecessary as the 'register_sidebar' function got introduced in wp2.2.0